# how to get full confusion matrix when using print(..)?

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

I would like to print out the confusion matrix. But when I do it, my output looks like this :

```
[[26  1  0 ...  0  0  0]
 [ 0 65 0 ...  0  1  0]
 [ 0  0 61 ...  0  3  1]
 ...
 [ 0  0  0 ... 30  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 ...  0 73  0]
 [ 0  0  0 ...  0  0 33]]
```

How can i get the full confusion matrix without these ...?

```
model.load_weights('action.h5')
yhat = model.predict(X_test)
ytrue = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1).tolist()
yhat = np.argmax(yhat, axis=1).tolist()
print(confusion_matrix(ytrue, yhat))
```

if I use a another model i dont get this problem. I've also used `numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)` but after running my file it will give nothing.

Comment: I guess you can use [`numpy.set_printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).

Comment: Is this `confusion_matrix` imported from `sklearn`?

Comment: What is the type of the confusion_matrix? Apparently, it's not a (normal) NumPy 2D array then, if setting the threshold doesn't work.

Comment: I've just tired with and with `numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)`, and with that setting, it prints the full confusion matrix, while without, it does not. In other words, I can't reproduce your example. Could you please make a reproducible example (that is, with dummy data included in the code in your question, as well as all the relevant imports)?

Comment: Ive used `from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix`